# An intelligent duplicate file finder for Linux

Tags: linux, file-management

What I am searching for is a software to find duplicate files in Linux. I am expecting it meets these requirements.

**Must haves**

- Runs natively on Linux (not through Wine or PlayOnLinux)
- Is able to find duplicates based on content (size, name or date don't matter)
- Manual selection and batch deletion of duplicates is possible
- Able to scan both ext4 and NTFS drives

**Optionals**

- GUI
- Sorting on the basis of size, time, no. of duplicates etc.
- Is open source

**Things that don't matter**

- Time it takes to scan drives
- Resources it eats while its scanning (CPU, GPU or RAM)

So any recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rmlint (http://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

- Runs natively on Linux
- Is able to find duplicates based on content
- Manual selection and batch deletion of duplicates is possible (creates a batch script for you to review / edit / run)
- Able to scan both ext4 and NTFS drives
- GUI (in [develop](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint/tree/develop) branch)
- Sorting on the basis of size, time, no. of duplicates etc.
- Is open source

Also, even though they don't matter:

- Is very fast
- Is light on RAM even with huge datasets

Extra points of note:

- Includes option for byte-by-byte file matches instead of SHA1 checksum
- Can output to csv or json so you can do further processing and analysis

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, rmlint definitely is faster than fdupes and loved how it made a shellscript for review. Its gonna be my primary dupe finder now ;).

Comment: // , I confirm the light CPU and RAM requirements. I recommend using the command line version, if you know how to do the whole ctrl+alt+t thing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLg4HWzlsE8 <<< This guy has a good video on it, although he doesn't discuss installation.

Answer (score 4):

[fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) should do what you want.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes):

> fdupes is a program written by Adrian Lopez to scan directories for
>   duplicate files, with options to list, delete or replace the files
>   with hardlinks pointing to the duplicate. It first compares file
>   sizes, partial MD5 signatures, full MD5 signatures, and then performs
>   a byte-by-byte comparison for verification.
>
> fdupes is written in C and is released under the MIT License.

Comment: +1 for a great suggestion, Its seems to be exactly the software i needed, a gui would have been good but it works great without it nonetheless.

Comment: If you like fdupes, you might also like the [samesame](http://samesame.kruijff.org/) suite

Comment: @baitisj Tried using samesame, its a good alternative for fdupes but it has its learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI, KDE has `komparator`:

http://komparator.sourceforge.net/

It uses the MD5 checksum and hasn't been updated since 2013, but it still works okay.

Comment: +1,Thanks for suggestion, it does work great.Though was using gnome which made installing it dependency hell for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please check findimagedupes (http://tuxdiary.com/2012/05/20/find-visually-similar-images-in-ubuntu/), a visually similar image finder on Linux. In addition to duplicates, it finds the same images with different resolutions, formats etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations – and thanks for sharing! While it certainly contains a solution, this post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Especially, your answer should show how the product meets the requirements and what makes it recommendable. Also [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the core behind that link (apt-get)

Answer (score 1):

**fslint**:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/

- runs natively and is open source: [is there in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/fslint)
- GUI and selection of dups to delete:

[image: GUI and selection of dups to delete]

- intelligent detection of duplicates, as said in [the FAQ](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/fslint/master/doc/FAQ):

> Q. What algorithm is used to check for duplicate files?
>
> A. On a standard install, you can see the script used in
>   /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup. In summary the algorithm is:
>
> 1. exclude files with unique lengths
> 2. handle files that are hardlinked to each other
> 3. exclude files with unique md5(first_4k(file))
> 4. exclude files with unique md5(whole file)
> 5. exclude files with unique sha1(whole file) (in case of md5 collisions).

- tools other than file duplicates (bad symlinks, empty directories etc)

Comment: fslint is still switching over from Python 2 dependencies, so isn;t a great option at the moment. Hopefully it'll be upgrade soon.